# Ingestion time partitioned Table in BQ was "made available" for queries almost 14 hours after the begin of day?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

We setup a streaming insert into a BQ table that is partitioned like this (ingestion-time partitioned):

```
Table Type Partitioned
Partitioned by DAY  
Partitioned on field _PARTITIONTIME
Partition expiration
Partition filter Required
```

We know the table had fresh data today because a preview in the BG console showed rows being added to the table.

We tried following query with 0 B result for several hours after the "start of UTC day":

```
select * from `MQTT_trackers_partitioned` 
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2022-06-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2022-06-02');
```

At about 13:30 UTC time today, this same query now shows "This query will process 285.99 KB when run." and worked fine.

Why did BQ take so long to make the partitioned table data available for the query to work? (13 hours!). We are inserting data every minute 24x7 on this dataset, I would expect closer to "real-time" performance for queries considering that these are frequent streaming inserts, are we missing some other detail to make this work?

Comment: BigQuery and MySQL are two diff animals; removing [mysql] tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does bigquery steaming buffer persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048726/how-long-does-bigquery-steaming-buffer-persist)